# Why do i get wrong object property from server?

Tags: java, json, spring

When I get List from server with spring I get in client object user like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "hgfhj",
  "age": 120,
  "createdDate": 1457211138000,
  "admin": true
}
```

UserController.java method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getList() {

        List usersList = userService.getList();

        ResponseEntity<List<User>> respEntity = null;

        if(usersList.isEmpty()){
            respEntity =new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            return respEntity;
        }

        respEntity =new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(usersList, HttpStatus.OK);

        return respEntity;

    }
```

And when I use Gson I get in client object user like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "hgfhj",
  "age": 120,
  "isAdmin": true,
  "createdDate": "Mar 5, 2016 10:52:18 PM"
}
```

UserController.java method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getList() {

        List usersList = userService.getList();

        ResponseEntity<List<User>> respEntity = null;

          respEntity =new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(usersList, HttpStatus.OK);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(usersList);

        return json;
    }
```

In all project user property name "isAdmin", I do not understand why it's changed to "admin". How can I use spring but get in client "isAdmin" without gson?

User.java:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    /*@Column(name="id")*/
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name="isAdmin")
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @Column(name="createdDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    private Date createdDate;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setIsAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explore User class little bit ? So that we get more idea to fix this.

Comment: @vishal gajera, I've added User class

Comment: what you want into response ? isAdmin or admin ?

Comment: @vishal gajera, isAdmin

Comment: please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*please do following changes into your User class's setter method,*

```
@JsonProperty("isAdmin") // i guess you want isAdmin into response..
public void setIsAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your User objects attributes with @JsonProperty to spesify the name you want as output.

Example

```
public class User {
    ...

    @SerializedName("isAdmin")
    @Column(name="isAdmin")
    private boolean admin;

    ...
}
```

this will return something like

```
{
    "isAdmin" : true
}
```

for more information: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/

---

Updated:
For future reference @JsonProperty("name") needs to be on the getters with gson, not the attributes.

Comment: Now i get:  ` {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "hgfhj",
  "age": 120,
  "createdDate": 1457211138000,
  "admin": true,
  "isAdmin": true
}`

Comment: Dont add the attribute.. You need to add the line to your User class before @Column(name="isAdmin")

Comment: I haven't added new attribute, just added  `@JsonProperty("isAdmin")` as you said

Comment: this is dependant on what parser you are using. try to use @SerializedName("isAdmin") instead of @JsonProperty(..)

Comment: This returns: `{`
   ` "admin" : true`
`}`

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new today. Gson is dependant on the getters to map correctly. With Jackson, attribute annotation is enough :)